# Paperclip converting adobe illustrator files to .txt, need to upload as is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, adobe-illustrator

Using the Paperclip gem with rails and whenever I upload a .ai file it converts to a txt file on aws s3.  How do I have it upload the file without any processing so when I download it is still an .ai file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the `gem "paperclip-dropbox"` which works perfectly. 
Available here: https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox